# Rails tabs navigation with tabs_on_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I want to use a tabbed navigation page for rails and I have used **tabs_on_rails** gem.
I have one tab rendered with `person_controller.rb` and two tabs rendered from `relationships_controller.rb`. Can I render two pages from the same controller using `set_tab`? If not, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do that
From example on the tabs_on_rails github page

```
<%= tabs_tag do |tab| %>
  <%= tab.home      'Homepage', root_path %>
  <%= tab.dashboard 'Dashboard', dashboard_path %>
  <%= tab.account   'Account', account_path %>
<% end %>
```

Here you can clearly see the root path and dashboard path are written.
You just have to replace it with controller action path. You can find path in just doing`rake routes`